# easylist in tabular

Tags: tabularx, mdframed, easylist

I'd like to build this table:[image]

As I have a very long list to itemize, I'd like to use easylist. Obviously the easylist-group causes problems in the tabularx-environment. That's what I coded so far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\mdfdefinestyle{round}{ % rund
innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=10pt,innerleftmargin=1pt,innerrightmargin=1pt,
middlelinewidth=3pt,innerlinewidth=0.4pt,outerlinewidth=0.4pt,
linecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,roundcorner=20pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=round]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{
            \begin{tabularx}{0.45\linewidth}{|X|}
                AAAA
                \begin{easylist}[itemize]           
                    & A1
                    & A2
                    & A3
                \end{easylist}
        \end{tabularx}} 

        & 

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{
            \begin{tabularx}{0.45\linewidth}{|X|}
                BBBB
                \begin{easylist}[itemize]           
                    & B1
                    & B2
                    & B3
                \end{easylist}
            \end{tabularx}}     

    \end{tabularx}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an easy job using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and there's no need for a tabular (I added some colors just to show off):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\tcbset{
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside]
AAAA
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & A1
  & A2
  & A3
\end{easylist}\tcblower
BBBB
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & B1
  & B2
  & B3
\end{easylist}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the colors and with the double frame, and the middle line not touching the borders:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\tcbset{
  colback=white,
  arc=10pt,
  colframe=black,
  freelance,
  frame code={
    \draw[double,rounded corners=10pt]
      (frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north east) --
      (frame.south east) -- cycle;
  },
  segmentation code={
    \draw
      ([yshift=5pt]segmentation.south) -- ([yshift=-5pt]segmentation.north);
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside]
AAAA
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & A1
  & A2
  & A3
\end{easylist}\tcblower
BBBB
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & B1
  & B2
  & B3
\end{easylist}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment a new requirement was made: to add a big plus sign in the left half and a big minus sign on the right half; this can easily be done using `interior code` (using appropriate shifts you can place the signs at the desired locations):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tcbset{
  colback=white,
  arc=10pt,
  colframe=black,
  freelance,
  frame code={
    \draw[double,rounded corners=10pt]
      (frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north east) --
      (frame.south east) -- cycle;
  },
  segmentation code={
    \draw
      ([yshift=5pt]segmentation.south) -- ([yshift=-5pt]segmentation.north);
  },
  interior code={
  \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}
  \pgftransparencygroup
  \coordinate (auxleft1) at ( $ (frame.north)!0.5!(frame.south) $ ); 
  \coordinate (auxleft2) at ([xshift=10pt] $ (frame.north west)!0.5!(segmentation.north) $ ); 
    \draw[line width=6pt,gray]
      ([xshift=-25pt]auxleft2|-auxleft1) --
      ([xshift=25pt]auxleft2|-auxleft1);  
    \draw[line width=6pt,gray]
      ([yshift=-25pt]auxleft2|-auxleft1) --
      ([yshift=25pt]auxleft2|-auxleft1);
  \endpgftransparencygroup
  \coordinate (auxright1) at ( $ (frame.north east)!0.5!(frame.south east) $ ); 
  \coordinate (auxright2) at ([xshift=10pt] $ (frame.north east)!0.5!(segmentation.north) $ ); 
    \draw[line width=6pt,opacity=0.5,gray]
      ([xshift=-25pt]auxright2|-auxright1) --
      ([xshift=25pt]auxright2|-auxright1);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside]
AAAA
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & A1
  & A2
  & A3
\end{easylist}\tcblower
BBBB
\begin{easylist}[itemize]           
  & B1
  & B2
  & B3
\end{easylist}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very powerful package. I read the documentation but couldn't figure out, how to add a big "+" in the background of the left and a big "-" in the right cell of the table. Tried the watermark and mybox-commands but it didn't work.

Comment: @Moldevort How big? Are the + and - signs some existing images you have? Also, take into account that in this site it's preferable to have one question per post.

Comment: it should look like this: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2ijghvk.jpg. There are no images, just a simple plus- and minus-sign. 
Unfortunately you replied quicker than I could edit my original post. ^^)

Comment: @Moldevort please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a `minipage` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- The following `mdframed` parameters have been tweaked:

  ```
  innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
  innerleftmargin=10pt,
  ```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\mdfdefinestyle{round}{% rund
innertopmargin=\baselineskip,innerbottommargin=10pt,innerleftmargin=10pt,innerrightmargin=1pt,
middlelinewidth=3pt,innerlinewidth=0.4pt,outerlinewidth=0.4pt,
linecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,roundcorner=20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=round]
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
                AAAA
                \begin{easylist}[itemize]           
                    & A1
                    & A2
                    & A3
                \end{easylist}
    \end{minipage}% 
    \vrule\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
                BBBB
                \begin{easylist}[itemize]           
                    & B1
                    & B2
                    & B3
                \end{easylist}
    \end{minipage}% 
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```